# Can we use odbc_connect to fetch data for a laravel application through any of avilable ORM

Tags: php, pdo, orm, laravel-5, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

All,

I am new to laravel and I am using it for one of my we application. My application deals with one database(snowflake) which doesn't have native driver support of PHP. So I am depending on ODBC driver, I can fetch data  correctly when I am fetching data through odbc_connect, but not getting exact data while connecting through PDO:ODBC.

As far as I know every available ORM is using PDO for connecting and query execution.

- Is there any way to replace ORM connection with odbc_connect
- If no, then how to handling this situation.

Please note : I am using snowflake as a data source only, so we don't need to consider this as a Model, but I don't know how to handle a data source(other than Database) in Laravel's context.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The project at https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc appears to attempt solving the exact ask here, to replace `PDO` with `odbc_*` functions while preserving all other framework functionality.